# Adding specific fill color to a specific road or getting geojson data of it

Tags: geojson, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-draw

I want to fill a specific road with a specific color using [mapbox-gl js](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/) or at least getting the **geojson** data of that specific road. Is there any specific and efficient way to get that done?

Comment: Show us your code so that users can understand what you are trying to do. This looks like you want help for the complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way around it.
At first, I generated geojson data of a specific road *(Beverly Glen Blvd, San Fernando, CA, USA)* using the http://geojson.io provided by [mapbox](https://github.com/mapbox).
After that, I added three properties to the properties object of that geojson data (id, name, color) and using that property named **color** to fill the road which I utilized using the **mapbox-gl js** get expression like this.

```
line-color": ["string", ["get", "color"]],
```

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/N_W_Turash/pen/arwqWg) demo.

```
map.on("load", function() {
  map.addLayer({
    id: "1",
    type: "line",
    source: {
      type: "geojson",
      data: {
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: [
          {
            type: "Feature",
            properties: {
              id: "1",
              name: "Beverly Glen Blvd",
              color: "#000000"
            },
            geometry: {
              type: "LineString",
              coordinates: [
                [-118.44586461782454, 34.15044515309062],
                [-118.44606578350066, 34.14968601019978],
                [-118.44618380069733, 34.14921542697057],
                [-118.44627767801283, 34.14880699411822],
                [-118.4463205933571, 34.14861165596896],
                [-118.44635546207427, 34.14842297664594],
                [-118.44640910625458, 34.148209879491944],
                [-118.44645202159882, 34.148043396966365],
                [-118.44650834798811, 34.14780144177757],
                [-118.44652980566025, 34.147717090264415],
                [-118.44678997993468, 34.1466293921546],
                [-118.44680070877074, 34.146573896977564],
                [-118.4468087553978, 34.14652950080971],
                [-118.44683825969695, 34.14650064328809],
                [-118.44687312841414, 34.14647844518782],
                [-118.44692945480347, 34.146436268781265],
                [-118.44693750143051, 34.14638299329021],
                [-118.4469187259674, 34.146307519620414],
                [-118.44689458608627, 34.146229826066346],
                [-118.44685971736908, 34.14617211080851],
                [-118.4468302130699, 34.14610995587136],
                [-118.44671756029128, 34.14576588307053],
                [-118.44666659832001, 34.14569040884941],
                [-118.4465754032135, 34.145561658551856],
                [-118.44654053449631, 34.14537075257705],
                [-118.44656199216844, 34.14531525657322],
                [-118.44660490751268, 34.14522202320469],
                [-118.44666928052901, 34.14508883249976],
                [-118.4467738866806, 34.14492900337667],
                [-118.44714134931564, 34.144345180538075],
                [-118.44724595546721, 34.144167591041665],
                [-118.44746589660645, 34.14389676634091],
                [-118.44773143529893, 34.143637040197646],
                [-118.44793260097505, 34.14342393097094],
                [-118.44798624515533, 34.143344014872326],
                [-118.44802916049957, 34.143264098698126],
                [-118.44805866479874, 34.14320860131048],
                [-118.44806134700775, 34.14311092581964],
                [-118.44804793596266, 34.14301325021589],
                [-118.44807475805283, 34.1428889356478],
                [-118.44817131757735, 34.142729102362914],
                [-118.44827055931091, 34.14261366702467],
                [-118.44845294952391, 34.14240721496879],
                [-118.44851195812225, 34.1422962190313],
                [-118.4486970305443, 34.14189441251827],
                [-118.4489169716835, 34.141448205256296],
                [-118.44912618398665, 34.14101087545433],
                [-118.44926834106445, 34.14073782067377],
                [-118.44944804906845, 34.14037596623108],
                [-118.44964385032654, 34.13998081052974],
                [-118.4498342871666, 34.139616732854655],
                [-118.44989329576491, 34.13949463328309],
                [-118.4500166773796, 34.139245993610096],
                [-118.45008373260498, 34.13912611350636],
                [-118.45019906759262, 34.13890411286514],
                [-118.45033317804337, 34.13872651193225],
                [-118.4505772590637, 34.13841792942364],
                [-118.45063894987106, 34.13832690846846],
                [-118.45148384571075, 34.13721910898561],
                [-118.45174133777618, 34.13687722004035],
                [-118.45193445682526, 34.136628572665956],
                [-118.45214903354643, 34.136368824181034],
                [-118.45228046178816, 34.13627114078354],
                [-118.45256745815279, 34.136073553566185],
                [-118.45295637845992, 34.13591592747724],
                [-118.45308512449263, 34.13582712391739],
                [-118.45317900180817, 34.135698358589856],
                [-118.45320314168929, 34.135449707746986],
                [-118.45313072204591, 34.135205496385616],
                [-118.45292419195174, 34.135010126788465],
                [-118.45279544591902, 34.1349612843186],
                [-118.45267742872237, 34.134919102162826],
                [-118.45248430967332, 34.13490578147768],
                [-118.45228046178816, 34.134932422845864],
                [-118.45213294029236, 34.134919102162826],
                [-118.45198541879654, 34.13490134124881],
                [-118.45173329114914, 34.134819196973034],
                [-118.45158040523529, 34.13473039226078],
                [-118.45145970582962, 34.134619386239216],
                [-118.45134437084197, 34.13446619769004],
                [-118.45125585794449, 34.13432188938248],
                [-118.45111370086669, 34.13414649895386],
                [-118.45094203948973, 34.13403327202814],
                [-118.4507355093956, 34.133933365791236],
                [-118.45047533512115, 34.133895623404335],
                [-118.45026612281798, 34.13390228382677],
                [-118.45004886388779, 34.13394890676917],
                [-118.44987988471985, 34.13402439147855],
                [-118.44961971044539, 34.13421976335437],
                [-118.4494024515152, 34.13435297119262],
                [-118.44921737909316, 34.13439959388638],
                [-118.44906449317932, 34.134415134778614],
                [-118.44894379377365, 34.13439959388638],
                [-118.44874262809753, 34.13434853093473],
                [-118.44855487346649, 34.13422642375129],
                [-118.44837516546251, 34.13379127671756],
                [-118.44833225011824, 34.13368026946253],
                [-118.44804257154463, 34.1329720397431],
                [-118.4478548169136, 34.132505803773135],
                [-118.4477823972702, 34.13242809752812],
                [-118.44766169786453, 34.13231042793535],
                [-118.44752490520476, 34.13224604261713],
                [-118.44723254442214, 34.13208174882427],
                [-118.4469884634018, 34.13191079413322],
                [-118.4468087553978, 34.13174871988604],
                [-118.44654858112334, 34.13159774633511],
                [-118.4459102153778, 34.131324661138855],
                [-118.44558298587798, 34.13124029317626],
                [-118.44531476497652, 34.13119366873973],
                [-118.44509482383728, 34.13114260385121],
                [-118.44451010227205, 34.13101161116996],
                [-118.4443598985672, 34.13095388551715],
                [-118.44417750835417, 34.13088727894572],
                [-118.4440889954567, 34.1308206723218],
                [-118.44387710094452, 34.13070522071602],
                [-118.44370543956757, 34.13064305440144],
                [-118.44350159168245, 34.13060309031791],
                [-118.44332456588745, 34.130583108269064],
                [-118.44320386648177, 34.13058532849696],
                [-118.44304293394087, 34.13062529258886],
                [-118.44287663698196, 34.130665256661906],
                [-118.4427237510681, 34.130762946538646],
                [-118.4425950050354, 34.13085397564034],
                [-118.4422704577446, 34.131053795275896],
                [-118.4420558810234, 34.1311359432113],
                [-118.44191908836363, 34.13113372299788],
                [-118.44180643558501, 34.13113816342467],
                [-118.44159185886383, 34.13111596128842],
                [-118.44143897294997, 34.131095979360815],
                [-118.44125390052795, 34.13109375914633],
                [-118.44108492136003, 34.131095979360815]
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    layout: {
      "line-join": "round",
      "line-cap": "round"
    },
    paint: {
      "line-color": ["string", ["get", "color"]],
      "line-width": 3,
      "line-opacity": 0.6
    }
  });
});
```